# Import existing SSH key to AWS EC2 programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, aws-cli

The official documentation on [Importing Your Own Key Pair to Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html?shortFooter=true#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws) is lacking in details on how to programmatically generate and import a key pair.

How to do it best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the key pair (max 2048 bits):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "ec2@aws" -N "" -f ec2_ssh
chmod 400 ec2_ssh*
```

Import public key to EC2:

```
aws ec2 --region=eu-west-1 import-key-pair --key-name ec2_ssh --public-key-material "file://ec2_ssh.pub"
```

The `file://...` feature is not mentioned for this command, but it is [described here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html#cli-using-param-file).

Sources:

- [AWS CLI Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-key-pair.html?shortFooter=true)
- [Uploading Personal ssh Keys to Amazon EC2](https://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-ssh-keys/)